# How do I locate child element using protractor locators?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Can you suggest locator for `<input>` element in the following DOM? by.repeater only gets me till    `<td>`   element. Any subsequent protractor locator is not locating `<input>` element underneath. Thank you in advance!

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tbody class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="devices in collection track by $index" >
        <tr class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"  st-select-row="devices" st-select-mode="single">
        <td>
            <chk-select class="ng-isolate-scope" emitselectedrec="selectedRows" chkmode="multiple" rowobj="clusters">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-transclude="" ng-click="pushToSelected(row)" uid="1">
           </chk-select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you would rely on the `chk-select` element and it's `rowobj` attribute:

```
element(by.css("chk-select[rowobj=clusters] input[type=checkbox]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use JavascriptExecutior driver. I will enhance my answer soon but you can do alot with this driver.

Answer (score -1):

In your case it's just `element(by.css('input'))`